# Firebase Android, set value where x = x?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this table in my database 
[image]

What I want to do is to set playerMoney to this specific user.

I get user email during authentication and using intent I move it to gameActivity.
There I have `mDatabase.child("users").child(u.getEmail()).child("playerData").child("playerMoney").setValue(Math.ceil(tap(playerMoney)));`

but using this causes `Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'`

This is my first time using Firebase so I'm not really that efficient in using it, I also couldn't really find anything online that would some-how help me.
Could anyone set me on a straight path with this problem?

Comment: What is `u.getEmail()`?  Does it contain anything in the list of characters you're told that are not allowed?

Comment: @DougStevenson 
I have `User u = new User();` and I set `u.setEmail((String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("User"));`
User is an object with ID, Email and DisplayName.
Therefore u.getEmail() equals the email seen in the database.

Comment: @Duzy Do you know the value you are setting here I think is what Doug was asking. Ex: if getEmail() returns "my@email.com", then that will be an invalid key.

Comment: @OneLunch Man
Thats exactly what getEmail returns.
My logic was if in `users` there is `my@email.com` then find `playerData` and in `playerMoney` setValue of `(Math.ceil(tap(playerMoney)))`

Comment: So, I feel like with this last comment and with your error, you have answered your own question- Are you using the email as a database path (.child)? Does it contain an illegal character?

Comment: OneLunch Man 
I underdstand the error I am getting, the thing is I cannot figure a way to do what I initially tried to do. Unfortunately I don't think there is `if(firebaseUserEmail.equals(u.getEmail)`, which is what I am trying to do

Comment: You can't use an unencoded email address as the key, since it contains a `.` character which (as the error message says) is not allowed. To use an email address as the basis of a key, you'll need to encode it. A simple encoding is to replace the `.` with a `,`, which conveniently can't occur in an email address/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to update the node for a user, based on knowing the email address of that user. To write any data to the Firebase Database, you need to know the exact path to the data you want to update. Since you don't seem to know the ID, you'll need to look it up based on the email address.

```
mDatabase.child("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo(u.getEmail()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            userSnapshot.getRef().child("playerData").child("playerMoney").setValue(Math.ceil(tap(playerMoney)));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Note that this type of query is often an anti-pattern in Firebase. Ideally you want to have a data structure that doesn't require you to query for such an update. For example, if you store users by their UID, you can perform the same update with this much simpler code:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(u.getUID()).child("playerData/playerMoney").setValue(Math.ceil(tap(playerMoney)));
```

Comment: I've seen this type of writing data (part 1 of the answer) but the problem I have with this that its never executed as if onDataChange was never called.
@edit. I got it actually working, the problem was on my end with
 `mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();`